# Extract array data into a file with yq4

Tags: yaml, yq

I have a yaml file say **sample.yaml** with the following structure

```
items:
  - version: v1
    data:
      file1.json: |-
        {
            "key1": val1,
            "key2": val2
        }
  - version: v2
    data:
      file2.json: |-
        {
            "key3": val3,
            "key4": val4
        }
```

In order to achieve the following output by splitting the data into separate files, what commands/operators should I be using in yq4? The documentation is rather confusing.

f1.json:

```
{
    "key1": val1,
    "key2": val2
}
```

f2.json:

```
{
    "key3": val3,
    "key4": val4
}
```

With yq3, I was able to run

```
files=$(yq read sample.yaml "items[*].data.*" -pp)
for file in $files; do
    yq read sample.yaml "$file" > f1.json
done
```

Any pointers would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Using [mikefarah/yq](https://github.com/mikefarah/yq) v4.14.1+ with `from_json` and the `-oj` option to convert to JSON, and the `-s` option to split up into files

```sh
yq -oj -s '"f" + ($index + 1)' '.items[].data[] | from_json' sample.yaml
```

will produce `f1.json`:

```json
{
  "key1": "val1",
  "key2": "val2"
}
```

and `f2.json`:

```json
{
  "key3": "val3",
  "key4": "val4"
}
```

---

If you want to use the filenames from the keys instead, you need to employ `to_entries` to have access to `.key` and `.value`. This will produce the files `file1.json` and `file2.json`:

```sh
yq -oj -s 'parent | .key | sub("\.json$","")' \
  '(.items[].data | to_entries)[].value | from_json' sample.yaml
```

Comment: Thanks for your help! Appreciate it. The second command was more helpful on yq v4.21.1. But with yq v4.14.1, I'm getting this error: `Error: unknown command "(.items[].data | to_entries)[].value | from_json" for "yq"`

Comment: @ninjacoder The second solution faces two issues with yq v4.14.1. The first is simple: yq v4.14.1 still requires you to provide the `eval` or `e` command. But the other is more crucial: `parent` was only introduced with yq v4.15.1. What you can do is not descending into `.value` (just updating it using `|=`). That way there's still access to `.key` for writing the JSON files, but their content has one additional level. You would need to iterate over them to fix. `yq -oj -s '.key | sub("\.json$","")' eval '(.items[].data | to_entries)[] | .value |= from_json' sample.yaml`